# How to update Json file before sending as a request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

In my Project, API Contract is changing frequently (every two sprints). From me it is very hard to update the payload in each 'http request' of project test cases.

I am looking for a solution to maintain a separate json file with the request. Update the request json file based on the test cases using **Jmeter** and send to server.

Do we have any solution for this?
Or please suggest if we have any other approach to handle this case.

sample JSON: original JSON has more than 600 lines.

```
{
abc:"abc",
xys:"xyz",
"abcd":[{
abc:"abc",
xys:"xyz",
abc:"abc",
xys:"xyz"
PQR:[{
abc:"abc",
xys:"xyz",
abc:"abc",
xys:"xyz",
}]}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I can think of only one option:

1. Add [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor), it will be executed before the request
2. JSON file can be read using [JsonSlurper](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonSlurper.html)
3. At this stage you can amend it according to your needs using [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)
4. Once you done you can construct the JSON back using [JsonBuilder](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/json/JsonBuilder.html) and write the generated new JSON back to the file

More information: [Apache Groovy - Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html)